# How to add line breaks to php message while sending email using mail function?

Tags: php, email

I have a variable say $message which contains the content to be sent in mail using php mail function. This variable $message will contain text that will also have line breaks. This variable data is being fetched from textarea of another file using ajax.

For instance, the actual text is:
**Hello

This is a test message**

So while sending mail ($message variable), I see **Hello This is a test message**, without line break. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: In PHP, use [`nl2br($message)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) for the text you are sending. This converts newlines from the `textarea` to actual newlines PHP can interpret.

Comment: I already tried nl2br but I get Hello \n This is a test message (in one line itself)

Comment: Instead of line break, I get \n character when I use nl2br($message)

Comment: Yes I'm using headers $headers = "" .
               "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion();
    $headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use like that:

```
$message = str_replace ('<br>' , '\r\n', $_POST['textarea']);
```

You can also use `nl2br()` function here.

Make sue you are using HTML header in `mail()` function.